# jenkins runAsUser: not working from helm deploy

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I have a jenkins pod up and running however I can't seem to get the job to run as any user other than jenkins.  Looking at the default values.yaml I see the following:

Enable pod security context (must be `true` if podSecurityContextOverride, runAsUser or fsGroup are set)
usePodSecurityContext: true
Note that `runAsUser`, `fsGroup`, and `securityContextCapabilities` are
being deprecated and replaced by `podSecurityContextOverride`.
set runAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
When setting runAsUser to a different value than 0 also set fsGroup to the same value:

I have defined the following in my values.yaml but the job still runs as jenkins:

```
agent:
enabled: true
runAsUser: 446 
runAsGroup: 446
```

job output:

- whoami
  jenkins

any suggestions?

Comment: which chart version do you use?

Comment: ***jenkins-4.3.30***

Answer (score 0):

settings for kuberntes plugin for default jenkins agent(jenkins/inbound-agent image), not for jenkins itself

aka plugin which will run pod in jenkins and will use it to execute your job on it

```
agent:
  enabled: true
  runAsUser: 446 
  runAsGroup: 446
```

[source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/templates/_helpers.tpl#L287-L288)

for jenkins itself(jenkins/jenkins image) its

```
controller:
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
```

[sources](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-controller-statefulset.yaml#L76-L98)

settings could be different if you use not latest helm chart